# Received an error in set(playerVal, scan.nextInt());

Tags: java

The code compiles without any issue, then I enter 0 it plays, then when entering X, it crashes with the error in set(playerVal, scan.nextInt());

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    createBoard(3,3);
    int turn = 0;
    int playerVal;
    int outcome;
    java.util.Scanner scan = new
        java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        displayBoard();
        playerVal = (turn % 2 == 0)? NOUGHT : CROSS;
        if (playerVal == NOUGHT) {
            System.out.println ("\n-0's turn-");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\n-X's turn-");
            }
        System.out.print("Enter row and Column:");
        try {
            set(playerVal, scan.nextInt());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
        {System.err.println(ex);}
        turn ++;
        outcome = winOrTie();
    } while ( outcome == -2 );
    displayBoard();
    switch (outcome) {
        case NOUGHT:
            System.out.println("0 wins!");
            break;
        case CROSS:
            System.out.println("X wins!");
            break;
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Tie.");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Be able to play the game when entering the 0 and X.

Comment: "it crashes with the error in set(playerVal, scan.nextInt());" what does the error message say? BTW as name of `nextInt()` suggests this method is supposed to handle strings representing integers like `"123"` not characters like `"X"`.

Comment: What @Pshemo: you're ignoring the most important information to be shared

Comment: It's probably an illegal argument exception, and it will probably be hard for us to answer without a [mre].

Comment: error message is as follows:  Enter row and Column:x
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at tictactoegame.TicTacToeGame.main(TicTacToeGame.java:125)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Pshemo - you're right, as soon I enter numbers, the game goes on, but when I enter a letter "X", it crash.  How should I go to fix that?